# Is there a function to determine the isomorphism of two graph drawings?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In a **drawing** of a graph, every vertex is assigned a dierent location, and
edges are drawn as simple curves between the locations assigned to their endpoints.

We say **two drawings of a graph** are **isomorphic** if there is a homeomorphism of the surface that maps one drawing to the other. But in actual operation, I find it quite difficult to determine whether two drawings are isomorphic. I don’t know how to describe homeomorphism.

For example, the following two drawings both show one graph K6 on the plane:

[image]
[image]
I don’t know whether mathematica  can do this judgment.

For plane graph We say that two planar embeddings of a
**planar graph G are isomorphic** if their **face boundaries** (regarded as sets of edges) are identical. This should be equivalent to the above definition based  homeomorphism.

By definition, the following two graph drawings are not isomorphic.
[image]

Comment: Please explain the question in full instead of giving a link. The page that the link points to may be changed or deleted (even if it is on another StackExchange site), therefore we generally aim to keep the questions self-contained, so they will be understandable even years from now.

Comment: sorry, I will modify it.

Comment: First, can you make the concept of _drawing_ more precise? How would it be represented on a computer? Do you need to handle curved lines, or can "drawing" be defined in a way that is independent of geometrical concepts such as lines/curves (something akin to combinatorial embeddings)? If [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051202/how-to-judge-the-isomorphism-of-two-drawings-of-same-graph#comment8367720_4051202) is correct, then it all reduces to an isomorphism test, but first you must determine the intersection, where my questions become relevant.

Comment: @Szabolcs For  non-planar graph drawing D, we can consider their associated plane graph that is obtained from D by turning all crossings of D into new vertices of degree four.  We consider whether both new plane drawings method are isomorphic, but the newly added vertices are still a bit different with Original vertex.

Comment: To turn this into a question that can be answered, you would need to see how Mathematica represents graphs. See the help for Graph and AdjacencyMatrix for two representations, and GraphData for a bunch of examples.  Then your question could be about a function relating such objects.

Comment: @Szabolcs A seemingly feasible solution is to find all the isomorphisms of the two graphs first, and then further determine whether any of their faces are also in a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: @bills thank you and I am familiar with the representation of these graphs in mathematica.

Comment: So say you want to represent two graphs by their adjacency matrix. Then your question becomes something like: under a given set of transformations on the matrix, can one one be transformed into the other? So you would need at least two things: to define the set of legal operations/transformations, and an algorithm to apply those operations to the matrices.

Comment: Is function `IsomorphicGraphQ` OK?